# Angularjs getting result of post query

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, http

I'm making search in BD MySQL, but I can't get result I need. This is php code

```
$mass = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
foreach ($mass as $mass_item) {
if($mass_item['name']=="Наименование" && isset($mass_item['val'])) 
$exp=$mass_item['val'];
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM Companies WHERE LOWER(name) RLIKE 
LOWER('".$exp."') ";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo json_encode($row);
}
```

This is an angular code 
`

```
    $http.post("search.php", value).then(function success (response) {
            console.log(response);
            console.log(response.data);
        },function error (response){
            console.log(response.data);
        }
    );`
```

As a result in console I see empty row "". But if I add one more echo before or in `while`, like `echo $row['name']` in console will be all 
expected result. I need to get query in json format to work with it. Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are trying to echo every row, change php code to something like that:

```
$resultJson = [];
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $resultJson[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($resultJson);
die;
```

Comment: can u help me one more time pls?) Now I get json objects, but properties are duplicated. Like {0:"John",1:"123",name:"John",phone:"123"}

Comment: @RoGGeR could you show problem? dump row in while loop and resultJson before encoding.

Comment: You mean make a new question?

Comment: Object
0
:
"qwerty 1121"
1
:
"8-81153-3-32-07;8-81153-3-32-07"
2
:
"7954"
$$hashKey
:
"object:173"
Legal_address
:
"7954"
company_phone
:
"8-81153-3-32-07;8-81153-3-32-07"
name
:
"qwerty 1121"        - this is what I get as a result

Comment: I forgot that its possible to edit exiting questions))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146239/discussion-between-kricha-and-rogger).